# Postgresql service could not start after replace data directory

Tags: windows, postgresql

I have a Windows Server ( called `X` server ) with Postgresql and data directory path is : `D:\pgdatabase`, I stop the Postgresql service and copy all data folder and put to another `Y` server the same location `D:\pgdatabase`

(Of course `X` and `Y` has the same setting for data directory location )

But when I start Postgresql service on `Y`, it's could not start and said that:

> The postgresql-x64-11 service on local computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs

Do I need additional setting to make postgresql service on `Y` work with new data?

//Update : 
I see this error in Event Viewer

```
2019-12-27 16:53:21 JST [75964]: [1-1] user=, db=PANIC:  could not open control file "global/pg_control": Permission denied
```

Comment: Maybe check the `pg_log` folder under your Postgres install to see if you can a more detailed error message.  Assuming there is something more required than moving the data directory, an error message might reveal that.

Comment: Apparently the user under which the Service runs on Y does not have the privileges to access the data directory

Answer (score 0):

I could resolved my problem, just grant access to full permission for this new data folder